# Adding Item to list on click Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have list that is created dynamically as shown

Now I need a `ADD` button, which on click will add new item to list automatically. Help me out with this please.

Comment: No down vote please, i am new to developing and i know some of you experienced guys may find it foolish.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Hi this is how can you retrive data using jquery


 $(document).ready(function () {

 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "URL/MethodName",
                data: "{}",// you can provide parameteres to your function here
                dataType: "JSOn",
                success: function (data) {
                     for (var i in data) {
                alert(data[i].Id); //assign to controls 
                  alert(data[i].Header);// assign to controls 
                  alert( data[i].Content) ;// assign to contols
            }

                   alert('Data fetched Successfully');



                },
                error: function (result) {
                  alert('Data not fetched ');

                    return false;
                }

            });
    return false;
 });


/*************************************************************************
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public ActionResult Careers()
    {
        List<JobOpening> job = new List<JobOpening>()
        {

        new JobOpening{Id = 1, Header = "Job1", Content = "edde" },
        new JobOpening{Id = 2,Header = "Job2", Content = "deded" },

        };



    }
```

Comment: Not working.:(  Hope you have understood my problem ??